# Schedule Dockerized Import Job in Azure

Tags: azure, docker, cron, microservices, docker-swarm

I have a cron running hourly inside a docker container (swarm) in Microsoft Azure.
The container is currently running all the time, and the (unix) cron keeps triggering the import script.

I would be interested if there is an elegant way of scheduling job. e.g using the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/

Say the scheduler spins up the container (starting the import script) and ending when done. It would handle execution intervals, failed jobs etc.

Any thoughts?

Cheers,
Tibor